# Updating belongs_to association with strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I've been using attr_accessible for a long time, and I'm struggling a bit adopting to strong params.

**models**

```
class Rule
end

class Account
  belongs_to :applied_rule, class_name: 'Rule', foreign_key: 'rule_id', inverse_of: false, optional: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applied_rule, update_only: true, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I'm trying to update the relation, and not having much success. With attr_accessible you would expose the relation itself, then use something like `@account.update(applied_rule: @rule)` and it would just work™.

**controllers**

```
class AccountsController
  def update
    if @account.update(account_params)
      render json: AccountSerializer.new(@account)
    else
      render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:name, applied_rule_attributes: %i(id _destroy))
  end
end
```

**specs**

```
RSpec.describe 'Accounts', type: :request do
  let(:account) { create(:account) }

  describe 'PUT /accounts/:id' do
    before { put account_path(account, params.merge(format: :json)) }

    let(:rule) { create(:rule) }

    context 'with good params' do
      let(:params) { { account: { applied_rule_attributes: { id: rule.id } } } }

      it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok) }
      it { expect(account.changed?).to be true }
      it { expect(account.applied_rule).to eq rule }
    end

    context 'when deleting relation' do
      let(:params) { { account: { applied_rule_attributes: { _destroy: true } } } }

      it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity) }
      it { expect(account.changed?).to be true }
      it { expect(account.applied_rule).to be_nil }
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this originally without the nested attributes - it still doesn't work, but I feel like it's heading in the correct direction.

I'd like to change the relation on the entity. I want to set the applied rule on an account to something different, or maybe even remove the applied rule from the account entirely (without deleting the rule, just the association). Is there an idiomatic approach to this?

**interesting code**

```
> params[:account][:applied_rule] = Rule.friendly.find(params[:account][:rule_id])
> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"account"=><ActionController::Parameters {"rule_id"=>"065230e1cb530d408e5d", "applied_rule"=>#<Rule id: 1, account_id: 3, name: "Rule 1", global: false, created_at: "2018-10-12 00:55:49", updated_at: "2018-10-12 00:55:49", slug: "065230e1cb530d408e5d">} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"accounts", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"account-2", "format"=>"json"} permitted: false>

> params.require(:account).permit(:name, :applied_rule)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
```

Comment: It seems to be Ok, the problem could be in the Form... When you make the submit what is the params structure?

Comment: This is API only, so I'm sending the params manually. I'll update the question to show the failing spec